# Reverse an array without reverse using shift, confusing result

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to reverse an array without using reverse() in javascript. There are many solutions to this problem on here, but I'm just curious to find out why mine doesn't work, because I can't figure out why I don't get correct results.

```
const reverse = (arr) => {
  const result = []
  let slice = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    slice = arr.shift()
    result.unshift(slice)
  }
  return result
}
console.log(reverse([1, 2, 3, 4]))
// output --> [2, 1]
```

Comment: `arr.shift()` shortens the array ... so, you'll only ever do half ...

Comment: why shifting `arr`? just peek its content...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always use `arr.forEach`. Something like:

```js
const reverse = (arr) => {
   let newArr = [];
   arr.forEach(el => newArr.unshift(el));
   return newArr;
}

console.log(reverse([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

This leaves the original array untouched, and just performs the action on each element.

I understand you seem to want to use shift and unshift, and it's possible, but if you do that, use a while loop, something like:

```js
const reverse = (arr) => {
  const result = []
  let slice = 0
  while ( arr.length > 0) {
    slice = arr.shift()
    result.unshift(slice)
  }  
  return result
}
console.log(reverse([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Comment: I think the issue is when you shift the array it shortens it's length and the loop doesn't run as many iterations as it should.

Comment: Indeed! That is the reason you were getting half a list. I provided a couple solutions, and I hope they work for you. If so, would you mind accepting this as the answer?